# Chartjs drill down issue with multiple Y-Axis Bar/Line graph

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have a bar chart with multiple Y-Axis as you can see in the image below.

[image: Multiple Y-Axis Graph]

As you can see the two bar represents two different datasets. The `onclick` event of the canvas provides us an array of all the bar points.

```
canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
    var activePoints = chartObject.getBarsAtEvent(evt);
}
```

Now the problem is that in our application we have do two different thing based on which bar the user clicks on. Using the above points we are not able to determine which bar the user clicked on, meaning if the user clicks on blue bar then we need to do something or else if the user clicks on purple bar then we do something completely different. How can we determine which bar the user clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no support for that, you have to implement it by yourself.
See https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3115#event-792845174 
See also this solution: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1283